# Is the price at a table inside and on the terrace the same in cafés in Italy?

Tags: italy, price, cafes

In Italy the price of the coffee is different if you drink at a table or stand at the counter in cafes (or takeout).

Usually, there are two items on the price list - banco and tavola, which corresponds to standing and sitting.

However, there is no mention of the price depending on whether the table is inside or outside.

I heard that in France there are three prices: standing, inside, and outside (example: [the comment #1](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187147-i14-k6895299-Costs_of_eating_in_sidewalk_cafes-Paris_Ile_de_France.html)). How about Italy, inside vs outside?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking there is no difference between sitting inside or outside, you are paying more just because you sit at a table.

This rule may be spelled differently on the price list, for example there is a single price and a "*servizio al tavolo*" extra.

In some places where you eat (restaurants, pizzerie, english style pubs) it may differ a bit... you are charged a "*coperto*" only if you eat and not if you drink only (coffee, soda, beer, wine or whathever).
The "*coperto*" is an extra charge for cutlery, bread and tablecloth.

I have no official source, I'm italian and lived in Italy for like 30 years.

Comment: Here in Portugal, just for reference, you can have a higher price when outside.